# Do not open a new tab for links at the Community Bulletin

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, community-bulletin

All links on the Stack Exchange sites open in the same tab, ...
... except for the ones in the Community Bulletin.

Could you remove `target="_blank"` from these links?

Comment: Links in close dialog also open in new tab. Personally I find it useful, as most likely when clicking it one still want to stay in the same page.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I use the middle-mouse button to open links in a new tab if I want to. I don't see a tremendous difference between Hot questions and the community bulletin, yet the open-link behavior is still different. (edit: I meant hot questions, not related questions)

Comment: Community Bulletin is for questions on different site (Meta) or blog posts, both means you're leaving the site you currently browse. Related questions are all in the same site.

Comment: Hmm... so you got a point there. Worth adding to your post to help convince others. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Those links open in a new tab because people were hitting them accidentally when trying to select a close reason. That is not a concern for the community bulletin.

Comment: Yes, please -- stop taking that choice away from me.  I know how to use right-click menus and I'm tired of the "huh, what?" because clicking a link (unbeknownst to me) added another tab to my many open tabs, which I'll only notice when I'm cleaning up hours from now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hot Network Questions open in the same tab. Which may have already been said and deleted?

Comment: @Raystafarian true, Rob said that and [this was my reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230761/do-not-open-a-new-tab-for-links-at-the-community-bulletin?noredirect=1#comment758103_230761), no idea why he deleted the comment.

Comment: I want to add that meta-posts opened from within meta is **also** added in a new tab.

Comment: The same request on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253503/1419007

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with the next build, community bulletin links should behave the same way as other links on our sites. Keep an eye out for rev 2014.6.26.2343.